# SQL Derived Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have `TableOne` with one column: `ID`. I want to add a derived second column, `NumSemesters` which should be the number of occurrences of `TableOne_ID` in a second table, `TableTwo`.

Essentially, `NumSemesters` should be the number of times `TableOne.ID` = `TableTwo.Student_ID`.

How do I alter my first table to add this second column?

In table one, `ID` is the primary key.

Comment: Why would you do that? You would have to keep the tables in sync. Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: @juergend Good point. I supposed I should consolidate and then go from there.

Comment: Well, what do you actually try to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (assuming you already created the column NumSemesters):

```
update TableOneset NumSemesters = b.idCount
from TableOne a left join 
(select Student_ID, count(Student_ID) as 'idCount' from TableTwo groupby Student_ID ) b on a.ID = b.Student_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT TableOne.ID, TableTwo.NumSemesters FROM TableOne INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS NumSemesters FROM TableOne GROUP BY ID) as TableTwo ON TableOne.ID = TableTwo.ID
```

Jim